# PyQt - Tab Management from Outside Class

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton, qtabwidget

I am designing an application using PyQt that will manage multiple instances of Selenium.  Each instance has a QFrame with unique information and controls and can be tabbed through from the main window.

```
class Instance(QFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.username = "whatever"

        ...

        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start')
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.engineStart())

        self.exitButton = QPushButton('Exit')
        self.exitButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.engineExit())

        ...
```

How it looks

[image]

Users should be able to create and delete instances at will.

Creating a tab is no problem.  I have a "+" button set as the `QTabWidget`'s `cornerWidget`.  It is connected to a simple method to add the tab.

```
class App(QFrame):

    def __init__(self):

        ...

    def addNewTab(self):
        t = Instance()
        self.tabs.addTab(t, t.username)
```

The problem is, how can I use the "Exit" button from the "inside" Instance class to remove the tabs that are managed from the main window's "outside" class?  I need some way to call `removeTab()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want you must create a slot in the main window, and connect it to the clicked signal of the button as shown below:

```
class App(QFrame):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def addNewTab(self):
        t = Instance()
        self.tabs.addTab(t, t.username)
        t.exitButton.clicked.connect(self.slot)

    def slot(self):
        self.tabs.removeTab(your_index)
```